# split a div in two halves to show hidden div with effect jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

Ok first of all i apologize for my question type but have failed to find right clue.I want to have a div effect just like in the given url.
what is the plugin that does the following effect

http://fmedias.com/straightway/index_light.html

when clicking on about us, services, contact us, features
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also it's not a bad idea to create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umeshgurung352/yyp5o5w5/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need any plugin for this . I have created a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/z5mko7pm/2/

Instead of using "cross image" i used label .You can use image in that case by using img tag

HTML

```
<div class="left">WELCOME</div>
<div class="middle">We Are</div>
<div class="right">
<label class="cross-img">close me</label>
<ul>
    <li><a id="li1" href="#">AboutUs</a>

    </li>
    <li><a id="li2" href="#">Services</a>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$("#li1,#li2").on('click', function () {
$(".middle").show();
$(".right").addClass('expandRight');
$(".left").addClass('expandLeft');
$(".cross-img").show();
});

$(".cross-img").on('click', function () {
$(".middle").hide();
$(".right").removeClass('expandRight');
$(".left").removeClass('expandLeft');
$(".cross-img").hide();
 });
```

CSS

```
.left {
border-right: 1px solid;
width:50%;
height:200px;
}
.expandLeft {
width:15%;
}
.right {
margin-left:50%;
margin-top: -200px;
width:50%;
height:200px;
border-left: 1px solid;
}
.expandRight {
width:15%;
float:right;
}
.middle {
display:none;
width:70%;
height:200px;
margin-left:15%;
text-align: -webkit-center;
margin-top: -200px;
}
.cross-img {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi! I updated your jsfiddle with css transition. Couldn't achieve the transition on close. [jsFiddle_Update](http://jsfiddle.net/z5mko7pm/3/)

Comment: I think you can add css transition in '.left' and '.right' classes too . Then the effect will be shown i guess .

Comment: Well, I tried that too... Even tried animating with jquery ui's removeclass animation, but that too didn't bring out the same effect as the question's link...

Comment: But I can't see any animating effect in the provided question's link ? It is opening up and geeting closed normally :P